# How to use HTML/CSS/JS to write a list of text with two checkbox in the same row

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can we implement a list of display values with two checkboxes corresponding for each display. Do we need to put all the text and checkboxes in a table form? 
For example the one may look like below 
[image]

Comment: Please post your attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this for each display

```
<span>Display 1</span> 

<input type="checkbox" id="display1Captured" name="display1Captured" checked />
<label for="display1Captured">Captured</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="display1Waived" name="display1Waived" />
<label for="display1Waived">Waived</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/). Once you have imported the css and js library along with the jquery library as shown in the [introduction](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/), you can use the Bootstrap [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/).

```css
.head {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
 }
 
 .checkbox-div {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 head">
        Captured
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 head">
        Waived
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        Display value 1
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 checkbox-div">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1">
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 checkbox-div">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        Display value 2
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 checkbox-div">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1">
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 checkbox-div">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Holy boilerplate. Neither Bootstrap nor jQuery are necessary for this. CSS grid is a thing, and jQuery provides little advantage over modern JS.